# Early morning car rental at Belfast Ferry Port?

Tags: car-rentals, ferries, northern-ireland

I'm considering a journey to Ulster and am looking into renting a car at the Belfast ferry port.  The Stena Line night ferry arrives in the morning at 6:30.  I believe this is at Victoria Terminal 4, West Bank Road, Belfast, BT3 9JL.  I've found a couple of companies that can do a pickup at the ferry port, but it appears both [Dan Dooley](https://www.dan-dooley.ie/) and Europcar only open at 9:00.  Is there any company that can deliver a car to the ferry port meeting the night ferry, or would we have to take transportation into one of the city or airport offices?

Comment: Where exactly are you arriving? Dan Dooley list their opening hours at Belfast Docks "AS REQUIRED", indicating a Meet & Greet Service.

Comment: @traindriver I will arrive with Stena Line, I believe at Victoria Terminal 4, West Bank Road, Belfast, BT3 9JL (added to answer).  It might be that my information on Dan Dooley opening hours was wrong and obtained from a meta car rental search engine (I don't remember right now).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lovely email chat with Michael at Dooley Car Rentals in Belfast, belfast  at dooleycarrentals.com, he confirmed that, "yes, 0630 collection is absolutely grand."

[When you book online](https://www.dooleycarrentals.com/), and select Belfast Docks (or any other location that have the Meet & Greet Service, you can specify the time you'll arrive. You'll want to include in your booking the ferry line on which you'll arrive, arrival date and time and the dock location.

And for making itself available 7 days a week, and having extensive service hours (nearly every hour of the day and night), it deserves a bit of a promo:

> [About Us](https://www.dooleycarrentals.com/about.php)
>
> Dooley Car Rentals is family run business with over 50 years of history and experience in the car hire industry. We take pride in providing our customers with a first class service and will always try to go that extra mile. We have 19 Car Rental locations across Ireland and we are one of the few companies that have locations in both Northern Ireland and Southern Ireland.
>
> We have desks in all the major airports arrivals terminals having recently taken a desk in Dublin Airport Terminal 1 and also in Terminal 2.

Here are the Dooley Car Rental locations:

- Dublin Airport Desks Terminal 1 & Terminal 2, Main Arrivals Hall, 7 Days a Week, 05.00-23.00 Daily
- Dublin Port/North Wall, Meet & Greet Service, 7 Days a Week
- Dublin City Centre, 09.00-13.00 Mon-Fri, 09.00-13.00 Sat, Meet & Greet Service, Later By Prior Arrangement
- Dun Laoghaire Ferryport, Meet & Greet, 7 Days A Week
- Dublin North City, 05.30-18.00 7 Days A Week
- Cork Airport Desk Main Arrivals Hall 08.00-23.00 Mon-Sun, Later By Prior Arrangement
- Cork Ferryport, Meet & Greet Service, 7 Days a Week
- Larne Ferryport, Meet & Greet Service, 7 Days a Week
- Kerry County Airport Desk Open For All Flight Arrivals, 7 Days a Week
- Shannon Desk 06.00-18.00, Later By Prior Arrangement, 7 Days a Week
- Galway, Meet & Greet Service, 7 Days a Week
- Limerick (Head Office), 09.00-17.30 Mon-Sat, Later By Prior Arrangement
- Belfast International Airport, Desk 08.00-18.00, Later By Prior Arrangement, 7 Days a Week
- Belfast City Airport, Meet & Greet Service, 7 Days a Week
- Belfast Docks, Meet & Greet Service, 7 Days a Week

Comment: Great commitment, +1! BTW, quick, enter while it's still April 1st: [April answerathon competition](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4392/32134)

Comment: @mts aren't you kind: I'm not competitive, just a LEETTLE bit compulsive, working on older questions, the ones for which the answer is no/but, or can't really be answered (unless your traveled that route that had seventeen connections and rode a donkey named Fred to the water hole in the oasis that only appears every 38 years).

Comment: Excellent!  We might do that!  Unfortunately, Dan Dooley is also far more expensive (factor 3) compared to some offers for the same period from Belfast City Airport, so we might not do it despite being possible.